# Why does java use Object instead of T[] in method declaration when Object actually refers to an array

Tags: java, generics

I was reading at the Oracle java API document about `System.arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)` method. `ArrayStoreException` is thrown when the src/dest argument refers to an object that is not an array. Then is it possible to to use Arrays or T[] in the method declaration? Something like:

```
System.arraycopy(Arrays src, int srcPos, Arrays dest, int destPos, int length)
```

or

```
System.arraycopy(T[] src, int srcPos, T[] dest, int destPos, int length)
```

Comment: Because a `T[]` can't be an array of primitives, while an `Object` can. Also, that method predates generics. And, `Arrays` is a collection of static helper methods; not an **array**.

Comment: Also, if `src` and `dest` are both arrays of a reference type, then they don't have to be the same type. For example, you can copy an `Object[]` to a `String[]` as long as all elements in the `Object[]` are instances of class `String`.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt: But it would still work even if `src` and `dest` are arrays of different types

Comment: @newacct I'm sorry ,what do you mean? You seem to be repeating me

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt: It would work with `src` and `dest` being arrays of different types either way.

Comment: @newacct Yes, that is what I'm saying in my comment. (But you will get an exception if the actual objects from the source array are not assignment-compatible with the target array) How is what you are saying different from what I was already saying? Or are you saying that it would work if src was an array of reference type and dest was an array of primitive type? (That would be incorrect)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt: You seem to be saying that when `src` and `dest` are both arrays of reference type, not needing to be of the same type is a reason to have the method that takes `Object` instead of the method that takes `T[]` (implying that it doesn't work for the latter). I am saying that it makes no difference -- it works for both methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.arraycopy()` can be used on both arrays of primitives, and arrays of references. `T[]` can only be used with arrays of references -- `T` represents a reference type. The only supertype of both array-of-primitives types and array-of-references types is `Object` (well, there are some interfaces like `Cloneable` and `Serializable` that are also supertypes for all array types but they are not appropriate).